# My command works on terminal but doesnt work on script in pi

Tags: linux, bash, shell, mount, pi

so I am trying to execute the command: `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/usb -o uid=pi,gid=pi`

It works and mounts my USB to the **/mnt/usb** directory.

so I wanted to create a script thats basicially this:

```
#!/bin/bash
    sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/usb -o uid=pi,gid=pi
    echo "Script Worked"
```

and aliased it to "**usbmount**".

When I call "`usbmount`" in terminal I get the output of "`Script Worked`"

but USB doesnt appear to be mounted. I made sure the command works, I looked at the fstab data and it is correct too..

*What am I missing? whats the problem?*

**Edit:**
When I tried the script with `#!/bin/bash -e` , it says `mount: uid=pi,gid=pi: mount point does not exist.`

**Edit 2:**
adding `sudo mkdir /media/usb; sudo chown -R pi:pi /media/usb` at the start of the script did not work either unfortunately.

**Edit 3:***
updated script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
    sudo mkdir /mnt/usb; sudo chown -R pi:pi /mnt/usb
    sudo mount -o /dev/sda1 /mnt/usb uid=pi,gid=pi


echo "Script Worked"
```

and the output I get is:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/usb’: File exists
mount: uid=pi,gid=pi: mount point does not exist.
Script Worked
```

Comment: Seems good to me. Maybe remove `sudo` and use `sudo ./usbmount` instead? Also, place the option `-o` directly after mount. Mingling those could result into an unwanted outcome. AFAIK every command is always `[CMD] [OPTS] [ARGS]`.

Comment: let me try that, thank you! I will update the post soon

Comment: Test it with -e `#!/bin/bash -e` or like so `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/usb -o uid=pi,gid=pi && echo ok || echo fail`

Comment: edited the main post

Comment: Is `/media/usb` there?, do you need to add `sudo mkdir /media/usb; sudo chown -R pi:pi /media/usb` to your script?

Comment: Hmm let me try that one!

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake there, you are using `mnt` instead of `media` so it would be `sudo mkdir /mnt/usb; sudo chown -R pi:pi /mnt/usb`

Comment: Put options before positional arguments. Anything else is nonportable. That is, `mount -o uid=pi,gid=pi /dev/sda /media/usb`. Even when your current operating system doesn't force you to follow that POSIX-standardized convention, you should be doing so as a matter of habit so your scripts don't break when run on more strictly compliant platforms.

Comment: @Bayou, FYI, the specification indicating that convention is at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html; see Guideline 9 in the list near the end.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I did do that Im going to post the updated code soon, Im working on another thing rn so might take some while

Comment: I *did* show you how to correctly fix the ordering in my comment above (moving the option argument along with the option). Is there a reason you didn't follow that instruction in the edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You moved the `-o` option without moving its argument. The `-o` switch and the string immediately after it are a unit.

Also, try `mkdir -p` to avoid getting an error message. Notice, though, that the error message suggests that the command tried to use `uid=pi,gid=pi` as the mount point; perhaps the `mkdir` was quite unnecessary all along.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

set -e

sudo mkdir -p /mnt/usb
sudo chown -R pi:pi /mnt/usb
sudo mount -o uid=pi,gid=pi /dev/sda1 /mnt/usb

echo "Script Worked"
```

As there is no Bash-specific code here, I switched to `sh`. I moved the `-e` option into the script so it doesn't matter how exactly you run the script.

Perhaps in some way it would be better to take out the `sudo` commands, and let the script fail if the user lacks the privileges or fails to run the script with `sudo`. Then the script is also suitable for running as `root`.